# Adding a title to the border of a JFrame Window

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I'm trying to add a title to the border of a JFrame Window, can anyone tell me how can I do this? I am using NetBeans

The title should be in this position:
[image]

This is what I tried so far:

```
package cinema.booking.system;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.*;

/**
 * @author chriz
 */    
public class About extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form About
     */
    public About() {
        initComponents();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome"):
        frame.setTitle("Welcome");
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.setTitle(title)`

Comment: Still not working :/

Comment: Please do not post an image of code, as I cannot copy and paste it into my IDE.  Please instead post a [mcve] (focus on "Minimal" and "Verifiable") that would allow me to see and understand the problem.

Comment: JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome");
     frame.setTtitle("Welcome"); 

Those are the only two lines of code I added

Comment: You must be calling `setTitle()` on the wrong frame, as neither of these lines will cause this frame to actually become visible.

Comment: I arranged to 'this.setTitle()' and it worked ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to set the JFrame title:

**I)** Set the JFrame title when you construct your JFrame:

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Title");
```

**II)** Once you have a valid JFrame object, you can call the setTitle method of the JFrame class:

```
jframe.setTitle("Title");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. You can do one of the following:

1. Use [`Frame#setTitle(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setTitle(java.lang.String))
2. Use [`JFrame#JFrame(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#JFrame(java.lang.String))

Since your class `About` extends `JFrame`, can just use the [`super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) keyword to solve all your life's problems. You can either use the superclass constructor, or invoke the `setTitle` method:

```
public About() {
    super("Welcome");
    initComponents();
}
```

or

```
public About() {
    initComponents();
    super.setTitle("Welcome");
}
```

Comment: If i put this in a method it will still work right ?

Comment: It is still remaining blank :/ Do I need to arrange "frame.setTitle("This.....");" according to the name of my JFrame? My JFrame is called 'About', so do I need to put it as "About.setTitle("This....");" ?